# Format a clickable link in a table in the terminal

Tags: rust

I'm making a command line tool in Rust that prints a table to the terminal. The table will contain some links that are too long to display in full so I want to show a display text instead (some terminal like iTerm2 support this).

Here's my MWE:

```
use tabled::{object::Segment, Alignment, Modify, Table, Tabled};

#[derive(Debug, Tabled)]
struct MyStruct {
    name: String,
    #[tabled(display_with = "display_option_link")]
    link: Option<Link>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Tabled)]
struct Link {
    pub text: String,
    pub url: String,
}

impl Link {
    pub fn new(text: String, url: String) -> Self {
        Self { text, url }
    }
}

fn display_option_link(o: &Option<Link>) -> String {
    match o {
        Some(s) => format!("\u{1b}]8;;{}\u{1b}\\{}\u{1b}]8;;\u{1b}\\", s.url, s.text),
        None => format!(""),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let items = vec![
        MyStruct {
            name: "Google".to_string(),
            link: Some(Link::new(
                "click".to_string(),
                "https://www.google.nl/search?q=rust+is+so+awesome".to_string(),
            )),
        },
        MyStruct {
            name: "Bing".to_string(),
            link: Some(Link::new(
                "click".to_string(),
                "http://www.bing.com".to_string(),
            )),
        },
    ];
    let table = Table::new(items)
        .with(Modify::new(Segment::all()).with(Alignment::left()))
        .to_string();
    println!("{}", table)
}
```

with this in my `Cargo.tml`

```
[dependencies]
tabled = "0.7.0"
```

When I run this it prints

```
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| name   | link                                                             |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Google | click |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Bing   | click                               |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see the column width for the link columns doesn't work correctly. I suspect the string formatting breaks something in the `tabled` crate but I'm not sure. Is there another way I can format the link? Perhaps make it fixed width? I took the string formatting from the `terminal-link` crate (which I couldn't get working through the API) but I don't fully understand what it does.

I tried limiting the column width but that completely broke the table. I also tried switching to the `cli-table` crate but that had the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `tabled` crate does not take escape sequences into account and thus it thinks the link length includes all invisible characters such as its address and escape characters. To have it account for them, turn on its `color` feature.